# How do I change the default checkerboard blocksize in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm currently experimenting with OpenCV's calibration toolbox and I'm using a default checkerboard pattern to calibrate a camera. I want to use larger checkerboard blocks so that I can stand farther away from the camera without affecting OpenCV's ability to detect the corners.

As I understand it, OpenCV is pre-programmed with default block-size values. My question is: is there a way to change this default block-size value in the code? And where would I change this? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV does not make any assumption on the physical size or the pattern size of your pattern.

That is, you can have any pattern with R rows and C columns.
It also doesn't matter if each block is 1 cm or 1 m.

The only thing you give to the [`calibrateCamera`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) function is the `objectPoints` and `imagePoints`.

The array-dimensions (sizes) of these parameters corresponds to the number of corners of your pattern.

`objectPoints` should contain 3D coordinates (well, planar coordinates in your case, by setting Z=0) of your checkboard corners. These corners should be scaled to the physical size of your checkerboard. That is, if a corner has row-column index `(3,1)` and each block side is 3 cm then the 3D coordinate would be `(0.09, 0.03, 0.00)`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but would you mind explaining the lines `objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)` and
`objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)` from [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#setup) exmple? It seems to create an array containing the corner index instead of the coordinate (eg. (3, 1, 0) and not (0.09, 0.03, 0))

Comment: It creates a 6x7 grid of 3D-points where each coordinate is (x, y, 0). The x and y coordinate is created by the `meshgrid` function that in this case creates a regular grid. Run the meshgrid command in the interpreter and look at the output and it will hopefully be quite clear.